# Android - AsyncTask fatal exception

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, android-asynctask

I load an image in Bitmap from the javaCameraView. This one is send to async task in order to send it to php file. During the first-second there is no problem. 
After this time, I have a problem of thread but I don't find a solution.
This is the LogCat :

```
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:375)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:238)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at com.example.objectDetect.SendData.getStringFromBitmap(SendData.java:186)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at com.example.objectDetect.SendData.doInBackground(SendData.java:63)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at com.example.objectDetect.SendData.doInBackground(SendData.java:1)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    07-25 16:36:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    ... 5 more
```

I think the problem is in this function but I don't know why :

```
private String getStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmapPicture)
{
     if(!bitmapPicture.isRecycled())
     {
         final int COMPRESSION_QUALITY = 100;
         String encodedImage;
         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, byteArrayBitmapStream);
         byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
         encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
         return encodedImage;
     }
     else
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

After a lot of test, I have a different logcat but it's always a problem of memory. I create a bitmap in thread in run function.

Herebelow the logcat :

```
    07-26 09:42:50.491: E/AndroidRuntime(31291): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-27487
    07-26 09:42:50.491: E/AndroidRuntime(31291): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    07-26 09:42:50.491: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    07-26 09:42:50.491: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
    07-26 09:42:50.491: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
    07-26 09:42:50.491: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.example.objectDetection.objectDetectionView$1.run(objectDetectionView.java:197)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you need to scale down your bitmap. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Yes maybe, but this problem appears around 1 or two minutes of test...

Comment: is base-64 encoding really necessary?  Working with the binary data will be much more efficient ...it's this operation that is consuming too much memory

Comment: Yes because I send it to a php in order to make a comparison on server.

Comment: You've got a Bitmap of a large photo, then create a byte[] array holding the PNG encoded binary data, then create a large base-64 string representation of this PNG data.  You've run out of memory.  Send binary data to your server, base-64 encode it there if necessary

Comment: I have tried without success. There is always the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what I came up with to avoid out of memory errors when loading bitmaps.

```
   private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String urlToUse) {
    Bitmap img = null;
    URL url;
    try {
       //A uniform resource locator aka the place where the data is       
       //located
       url = new URL(urlToUse);
       //Opens an HTTPUrlConnection and downloads the input stream into a
       //Bitmap
       final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       // Prevents loading of image into memory and just ascertains bounds and memory footprint
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

       BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream(),null,options); // gather image data
       options.inSampleSize = Photo.calculateInSampleSize(options, 
               Photo.THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, Photo.THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT);
       options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
       img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream(),null,options);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       Log.i("PAR", "URL is malformed");
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.i("PAR", "Failed to decode Bitmap");
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return img;

} // end load function


public static int calculateInSampleSize(
    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        } // end if
    } // end out if
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

The key thing to ascertain here is the the initial load doesn't include the entire image. The flag inJustDecodeBounds is set to true, which does exactly as it sounds. It only decodes the bounds so you can determine ahead of time if the image may be too large. My suggestion is to determine the bounds and other relevant data, then do tweaking before loading all of the image. For this example, I am converting large images to thumbnails.

Using this technique should reduce the image sizes before you compress them. I suppose the tradeoff is you are reducing the images on load, which could mean lower quality. But, if you are running out of memory, this could be a viable alternative if you are willing to shrink the images a bit.

Comment: The problem is the bitmap is load from javacamera view. So I load a matrix.

Comment: You should probably include more information about your problem in the question. It is difficult to provide a good answer with what is provided.

Comment: I load an image in Bitmap from the javaCameraView. This one is send to async task in order to send it to php file.

Comment: You should include more detailed information in the question so everyone has the correct context to assist you. Make an edit to the original question